# Detect files with multiple extensions

Tags: linux, nas, find, sed, deduplication

I've a synology running a kind of linux OS.
I've transfered there a lot of photos.
Unfortunately, some are with .jpg and some with .JPG depending of the tool I used to import.
These are considered as different on the synology, but Windows doesn't like that much.

So now, I'm trying to detect the files that have the same name but a different extension
i.e.: "2020-02-13 17.37.08.jpg" and "2020-02-13 17.37.08.JPG"

Do you have any smart idea, because a `find`, with a `while read`, a `sed` and some `wc -l` including some `if` to exclude single files doesn't sound nice at all.

Thank you

EDIT: Here is one exemple

```
-rwxrwxrwx+   1 admin users          5815479 Jun 25  2021 2019-02-16 13.40.39.jpg
-rwxrwxrwx+   1 admin users          1759872 Oct 14  2021 2019-02-16 13.40.39.JPG
```

Comment: do the files actually contain the same content?

Comment: hmmm ... hard to tell, as it is imported from my iPhone. It might but if I used the Windows import tool, it is compressed in a different way than if I did with the synology tool. It is not noticable from "the naked eye". I therefore keep the biggest one. This is why I'd like to have a list, so I can compare them myself. I took a Windows tool called "Awesome Duplicate Photo Finder" but it is not comparing the 2 files as it is the same file (from a windows point of view)

Comment: Do you want to find such files across multiple subdirectories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No `while read`, `wc` or `if`, but using `find`, `sed` and some other tools that I hope are present in the Synology shell (mine appears to, anyway):

```shell
find . -type f -print0 | \
xargs -0n1 basename | \
sed 's/\.[^\.]\+$//' | \
sort | \
uniq -c | \
egrep -v '^      1'
```

This version takes the names of the files within the directory (that's what `basename` is for), strips the final extension off, and then sorts the results, counts how many of each we find in the sorted list, and excludes (`egrep -v` the ones that are just one instance of the extension-less filename. The `-print0` in combination with the `xargs -0` is to handle spaces in names by telling both commands to expect null characters instead of newlines to separate the paths/filenames from each other.

This will also list files that have both a `.jpg` and a `.mov` extension, for instance.

If you don't want to find matches across subdirectories, you can try this (similar) approach:

```shell
find . -type f -print | \
sed 's/\.[^\.]\+$//' | \
sort | \
uniq -c | \
egrep -v '^      1'
```

These are fairly short one-liners, only spread out over multiple lines for (your) readability.

Example:

```
$ ls -lR dir2/
dir2/:
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 userid unixusers 0 Jun 28 19:29 2020-02-13 17.37.08.JPG
-rw-r--r--. 1 userid unixusers 0 Jun 28 19:29 2020-02-13 17.37.08.jpg
```

And

```
$ find . -type f -print | sed 's/\.[^\.]\+$//' | sort | uniq -c | egrep -v '^      1'
      2 ./dir2/2020-02-13 17.37.08
```

Alternatively, across different directories:

```
./dir1:
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 userid unixusers 0 Jun 28 19:29 2020-02-13 17.37.08.JPG

./dir2:
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 userid unixusers 0 Jun 28 19:29 2020-02-13 17.37.08.jpg
```

And the output:

```
$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0n1 basename | sed 's/\.[^\.]\+$//' | sort | uniq -c | egrep -v '^      1'
      2 2020-02-13 17.37.08
```

Comment: Wow, that works very well. But, for a weird reason, I had to egrep -v -e '^      1' -e '^      2' because when there is 2 files, the uniq -c is displaying 3 and so forth.

Comment: One possibility is that you may have a symlink in your directory tree, causing certain files to be visited more than once.